# Irrationality of $\int_{-a}^ax^nn^xd x$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $a$ a positive real number. Is the below number irrational?

$$
N=\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}{x^n}{n^x}d x.
$$

The closed form of this integral is related to the $\Gamma$ function and $\log $ function as shown below in **note**, which assures me that is always irrational , the weaker luck is to get it rational. Then my question is:

> When is $N=\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}{x^n}{n^x}d x\,$ a rational number ?

**note:** $N=\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}{x^n}{n^x}d x\,=\displaystyle[_{-a}^{a}\frac{x^n(-x\log n))^{-n}\Gamma(n+1,-x\log n))}{\log n}$

Comment: «Below» is written with one L.

Comment: Fix any positive integer $n$. The function $a\mapsto \int_{-a}^ax^nn^xdx$ is continuous and non-constant, so there exist values of $a$ for which its value is rational.

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles please.